# Azure devops, how are work items linked to git commits by "work item mentioning"?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I pushed a git repo to a new Azure DevOps site/Organization and I did not turn off "[Commit Mention Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)."  So, when I pushed this whole repo to the new server like this:

```
git remote add origin git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/MyOrg/MyProj 
git push -u origin --all
```

It tries to link to all existing work items by Id.  Well, the original work items did not exist under this new Organization, *BUT WORK ITEMS WITH THOSE IDS DID EXIST*, so it linked the Commits to the incorrect work items, in an entirely different project for this Organization.

My questions - If I were to:

1. Delete my repo
2. Create a new repo
3. Turn commit mention linking OFF for this repo.
4. Push my local repo to the newly created repo

After step 1, I expect the Work Item to show the following for the linked commit:

[image: "Commit not found or no permission to access it".]

Question 1.

After step 4, I am hoping no new link would now be made to any work item, since I turned commit mention linking off.  Is this true?

Question 2.

But what is the nature of the "orphaned link"?  Is it made in such a way that re-pushing the original repo, there will be enough meta that it will somehow link back up by the commit sha or something? Or, will it remain "Not found".?

So I am really asking, how does this work under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1.

> After step 4, I am hoping no new link would now be made to any work item, since I turned commit mention linking off. Is this true?

The answer is yes. No new link would now be made to any work item and the previous link still remains invalid.

Question 2.

> But what is the nature of the "orphaned link"? Is it made in such a way that re-pushing the original repo, there will be enough meta that it will somehow link back up by the commit sha or something? Or, will it remain "Not found".?

The link points to the commit ID. Even though you delete the repository and recreate a new one with same name, the commit IDs won't be same. So it will remain "Not found".

The ID of a work item is not allowed to be duplicate within an organization. When "Commit Mention Linking" is turned on and commit messages contains "#{number}", an **organization-wide** search is made for the work item whose id is {number}.

So if you want to import a repository in a new project, notice the commit message or turn "Commit Mention Linking" off.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to clean up the links on the incorrect work items short of manually removing links on all of them?

Comment: it looks like the git commit details will still try to provide a href link to the wrong work item, at least within the project. My test case, the work item didn't exist but if it does?

Comment: @user210757 Just to make sure I get your point. You turned the Commit Mention Linking off, but links were still created?

Comment: no if you have a commit message of #10, when you go to the commit details it gives a hyperlink to this commit, even though it doesn't exist.  I haven't yet tested when it does exist, but I believe it will go to the wrong work item.